# Javascript to access element from parent page in iframe - how to reference the parent and the element

Tags: javascript

I have a form that accesses an element on a page and stores it in a hidden field (sendto). I then use this field to populate the recipient address when the form data is emailed.

The following script works fine when the form is hosted in the content of the page or in a module posiiton on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function test() {
    jQuery('#sendto').val(jQuery('.element-4732132c-bbbb-4f11-8179-8fa38301d8a9').text());
});
</script>
```

The function is called when the submit button is pressed.

But when the form is hosted in an iframe it doesn't seem to access the element to populate the hidden field.

I've tried changing 'document' to 'window.parent.document' and 'window.top.document' but that didn't work. I also tried '.window.parent.element-etcetcetc...' and that didn't work either.

I'm guessing it is to do with how the element on the parent page is referenced, but I can't guess what the problem is.  I've searched the questions here and whilst many seem to address similar issues none is specific to my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some HTML code also, so that we can see what is wrong

Comment: I use the Joomla CMS. The javascript is included as a function in a component that I use. I don't write the html.